# How to save an excel made with workbook(openpyxl) to azure storage account as blob in python?

Tags: python, excel, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Consider there is an workbook we made :

```
wb = Workbook()
```

and after writing code, we have excel created in that. But at last, instead of wb.save("test.xslx), I want to save this excel in the azure storage account as a blob.

I have tried saving the workbook(wb) in my azure storage account but it didn't work.

**Could you please help me how to do that?**

Comment: Can you paste the code here which you tried and the error if any?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code from the Azure docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python:

```
# Create a local directory to hold blob data
local_path = "./data"
os.mkdir(local_path)

# Create a file in the local data directory to upload and download
local_file_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"
upload_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, local_file_name)

# Write text to the file
file = open(upload_file_path, 'w')
file.write("Hello, World!")
file.close()

# Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)

print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\n\t" + local_file_name)

# Upload the created file
with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

Comment: I want a way to directly save it to storage account, not saving it in local system first.

Comment: The file created would be located somewhere on your local machine.